# How to embed YouTube player in Meteor App?

Tags: meteor, youtube, cordova-ios, meteor-cordova

I put a `YouTube` video with `iframe` in my HTML code and it shows up in my `localhost` version, but not on iOS simulator. Is there anything wrong? How can I embed a YouTube video in my `myApp.html` so that it will show up both in iOS simulator and localhost?

It seems that this should be okay if I use `Meteor` package like this one (1). But is there any other way to do this without having to install a package?

1. https://atmospherejs.com/adrianliaw/youtube-iframe-api

Comment: can you show your iframe html code? iOS doesn't support flash (I think), so maybe you just need to use a different type of player, which I assume can be specified in the iframe code.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get youtube videos working with fairly standard iFrames:

```
<iframe ng-if="video.youtube_url_2" ng-src="{{video.youtube_url_2}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The key was to create a `mobile-config.js` file (put it in the root of the project, alongside your README file and so forth) with the following rules (I suspect it was the first one that did it, including both 'just in case' -- this was literally a problem that fixed itself when I fixed a second issue):

```
App.accessRule('*', {type:'navigation'});
App.accessRule('maps:*', {type:'intent'});
```